warnings when creating booking with infant in sabre
I am trying to create a Passenger Name Record (PNR) for a one-way flight with one adult, one child, and one infant using the following JSON request in Postman:
{
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
    "version": "2.4.0",
    "targetCity": "XXXX",
    "haltOnAirPriceError": true,
    "TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
        "AgencyInfo": {
            "Ticketing": {
                "TicketType": "XXXX"
            },
            "Address": {
                "AddressLine": "123 Main St, New York, NY, 10001",
                "CityName": "New York",
                "PostalCode": "12345",
                "VendorPrefs": {
                    "Airline": {
                        "Hosted": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "CustomerInfo": {
            "ContactNumbers": {
                "ContactNumber": [
                    {
                        "NameNumber": "1.1",
                        "Phone": "817-555-1212",
                        "PhoneUseType": "9"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "PersonName": [
                {
                    "NameNumber": "1.1",
                    "GivenName": "Yoshi Miss",
                    "Surname": "Jefferson",
                    "PassengerType": "ADT",
                    "Infant": false
                },
                {
                    "NameNumber": "1.1",
                    "GivenName": "INF",
                    "Surname": "Wilkinson",
                    "PassengerType": "INF",
                     "NameReference": "I01",
                    "Infant": true
                }
            ],
            "Email": [
                {
                    "Address": "mail@gmail.com",
                    "NameNumber": "1.1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "SpecialReqDetails": {
        "SpecialService": {
            "SpecialServiceInfo": {
                "SecureFlight": [
                    {
                        "SegmentNumber": "A",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1",
                            "GivenName": "Yoshi Miss",
                            "Surname": "Jefferson",
                            "Gender": "F"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "SegmentNumber": "A",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "2.1",
                            "GivenName": "INF",
                            "Surname": "Wilkinson",
                            "Gender": "F"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Service": [
                    {
                        "SSR_Code": "OTHS",
                        "Text": "CC MANZOOR",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1"
                        },
                        "SegmentNumber": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "SSR_Code": "INFT",
                        "Text": "Wilkinson/INF/10NOV24",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "SSR_Code": "CTCM",
                        "Text": "8175551212",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1"
                        },
                        "SegmentNumber": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "SSR_Code": "CTCE",
                        "Text": "mail@gmail.com",
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1"
                        },
                        "SegmentNumber": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "AdvancePassenger": [
                    {
                        "Document": {
                            "IssueCountry": "PK",
                            "NationalityCountry": "PK",
                            "ExpirationDate": "2029-07-26",
                            "Number": "DY0714511",
                            "Type": "P"
                        },
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1",
                            "GivenName": "Yoshi Miss",
                            "Surname": "Jefferson",
                            "Gender": "F",
                            "DateOfBirth": "1990-06-24"
                        },
                        "SegmentNumber": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "Document": {
                            "IssueCountry": "PK",
                            "NationalityCountry": "PK",
                            "ExpirationDate": "2029-02-20",
                            "Number": "DY0714511",
                            "Type": "P"
                        },
                        "PersonName": {
                            "NameNumber": "1.1",
                            "GivenName": "Evelyn INF",
                            "Surname": "Wilkinson",
                            "Gender": "F",
                            "DateOfBirth": "2024-10-10"
                        },
                        "SegmentNumber": "A"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "AirBook": {
        "OriginDestinationInformation": {
            "FlightSegment": [
                {
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2025-01-04T12:20:00",
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2025-01-04T14:50:00",
                    "FlightNumber": "625",
                    "NumberInParty": "1",
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "Y",
                    "Status": "NN",
                    "DestinationLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "DXB"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "EK",
                        "FlightNumber": "625"
                    },
                    "OriginLocation": {
                        "LocationCode": "LHE"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "RedisplayReservation": {
            "NumAttempts": 5,
            "WaitInterval": 100
        }
    },
    "AirPrice": [
        {
            "PriceRequestInformation": {
                "Retain": true,
                "OptionalQualifiers": {
                    "FOP_Qualifiers": {
                        "BasicFOP": {
                            "Type": "CA"
                        }
                    },
                    "PricingQualifiers": {
                        "PassengerType": [
                            {
                                "Code": "ADT",
                                "Quantity": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "Code": "INF",
                                "Quantity": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "PostProcessing": {
        "EndTransaction": {
            "Source": {
                "ReceivedFrom": "TEST"
            },
            "Email": {
                "Ind": true
            }
        },
        "RedisplayReservation": {},
        "PricingInterval": {
            "waitInterval": 100
        }
    }
}

}
the response that im getting is as follow
   "ApplicationResults": {
        "status": "Complete",
        "Success": [
            {
                "timeStamp": "2024-12-07T14:42:07.862Z"
            }
        ],
        "Warning": [
            {
                "type": "BusinessLogic",
                "timeStamp": "2024-12-07T14:42:04.278Z",
                "SystemSpecificResults": [
                    {
                        "Message": [
                            {
                                "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                "content": "TravelItineraryAddInfoLLSRQ: .PASSENGER TYPE ENTERED VALID ONLY FOR INFANT NAME"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "BusinessLogic",
                "timeStamp": "2024-12-07T14:42:07.021Z",
                "SystemSpecificResults": [
                    {
                        "Message": [
                            {
                                "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                "content": "SpecialServiceLLSRQ: ‡INVALID COUNTRY CODE - SEE HCCC/‡"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "BusinessLogic",
                "timeStamp": "2024-12-07T14:42:07.161Z",
                "SystemSpecificResults": [
                    {
                        "Message": [
                            {
                                "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE",
                                "content": "EndTransactionLLSRQ: INFANT DETAILS REQUIRED IN SSR - ENTER 3INFT/..."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "BusinessLogic",
                "timeStamp": "2024-12-07T14:42:07.543Z",
                "SystemSpecificResults": [
                    {
                        "Message": [
                            {
                                "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.WARNING_RESPONSE",
                                "content": "EndTransactionLLSRQ: TTY REQ PEND"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

What changes are required in my JSON request to fix these warnings? Any guidance on handling infants and associating them correctly in the request is appreciated.

the below body uses Passanger name record api to create a booking containing 1 adult,1child,1 held infant in sabre
{ "CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ": {
"version": "2.5.0",
"haltOnAirPriceError": true,
        "targetCity": "XXXX",

"TravelItineraryAddInfo": {
  "AgencyInfo": {
    "Ticketing": {
      "TicketType": "7TAW"
    }
  },
  "CustomerInfo": {
    "ContactNumbers": {
                "ContactNumber": [
                    {
                        "NameNumber": "1.1",
                        "Phone": "222-555-3333",
                        "PhoneUseType": "9"
                    }
                ]
            },
         "Email": [
                {
                    "Address": "email@gmail.com",
                    "NameNumber": "1.1"
                }
            ],
    "PersonName": [
      {
        "NameNumber": "1.1",
        "NameReference": "A22",
        "PassengerType": "ADT",
        "GivenName": "Syed",
        "Surname": "Umer"
      },
      {
        "NameNumber": "2.1",
        "NameReference": "C6",
        "PassengerType": "CNN",
        "GivenName": "Child",
        "Surname": "One"
      },
      {
        "NameNumber": "3.1",
        "NameReference": "I10",
        "PassengerType": "INF",
        "GivenName": "Infant",
        "Surname": "Female",
        "Infant":true
      }
    ]
  }
},
"AirBook": {
  "OriginDestinationInformation": {
    "FlightSegment": [
      {
        "ArrivalDateTime": "2025-01-02T00:05:00",
        "DepartureDateTime": "2025-01-01T21:35:00",
        "FlightNumber": "623",
        "NumberInParty": "2",
        "ResBookDesigCode": "K",
        "Status": "NN",
        "InstantPurchase": false,
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "DXB"
        },
        "MarketingAirline": {
          "Code": "EK",
          "FlightNumber": "623"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LHE"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "RedisplayReservation": {
    "NumAttempts": 2,
    "WaitInterval": 5000
  }
},
"AirPrice": [{
  "PriceRequestInformation": {
    "Retain":true,
    "OptionalQualifiers": {
      "FOP_Qualifiers": {
        "BasicFOP": {
          "Type": "CA"
        }
      },
      "PricingQualifiers": {
        "CurrencyCode": "PKR",
        "PassengerType": [
          { "Code": "ADT", "Quantity": "1" },
          { "Code": "CNN", "Quantity": "1" },
          { "Code": "INF", "Quantity": "1" }
        ]
      }
    }
  } } ], "SpecialReqDetails": {
  "SpecialService": {
    "SpecialServiceInfo": {
      "SecureFlight": [
        {
          "SegmentNumber": "A",
          "PersonName": {
            "DateOfBirth": "2002-04-15",
            "Gender": "M",
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "GivenName": "Syed",
            "Surname": "Umer"
          },
          "VendorPrefs": {
            "Airline": { "Hosted": false }
          }
        },
        {
          "SegmentNumber": "A",
          "PersonName": {
            "DateOfBirth": "2017-11-11",
            "Gender": "M",
            "NameNumber": "2.1",
            "GivenName": "Child",
            "Surname": "One"
          },
          "VendorPrefs": {
            "Airline": { "Hosted": false }
          }
        },
        {
          "SegmentNumber": "A",
          "PersonName": {
            "DateOfBirth": "2024-03-17",
            "Gender": "F",
            "NameNumber": "1.1",
            "GivenName": "Infant",
            "Surname": "Female"
          },
          "VendorPrefs": {
            "Airline": { "Hosted": false }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Service": [
        {
          "SSR_Code": "CHLD",
          "PersonName": { "NameNumber": "2.1" },
          "Text": "11Nov17"
        },
        {
          "SSR_Code": "INFT",
          "PersonName": { "NameNumber": "1.1" },
          "Text": "Female/Infant/17Mar24-1.1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
"PostProcessing": {
  "EndTransaction": {
    "Source": {
      "ReceivedFrom": "SP TEST"
    }
  }
}}}


Could you explain what is the key difference between OP's code and yours?

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredgeThe key difference is that the OP's original response included a warning related to 3INFT. the error was that SSRS was not implemented correctly. In response, that i provided  is a complete and correct format for handling adults, children, and infants, ensuring the proper implementation.
